# How to run CodeIgniter app in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla2.5

We have some apps developed in a single installation of CodeIgniter, where each controller is a different app.

We need to make it so that when a certain Joomla 2.5 article is loaded, it runs the CodeIgniter app, gets the resulting html from it, and shows it on the Joomla 2.5 site where the article would be loaded.

Some more useful information: the apps contain forms, which work via post.

Update: I tried opening an `<iframe src="localhost/myapp/mycontroller/"></iframe>`in the article html editor, but it seems it doesn't allow that. The iframe just disappears.

Comment: So what have you tried?  Any code you can show us?

Comment: I'm 100% new to Joomla, so I really don't know what can or can't be done. I tried opening an <iframe src="localhost/myapp/mycontroller/"/>in the article html editor, but it seems it doesn't allow that. The iframe just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a solution. Not very elegant or convenient at all, but it allows me to do what I want to do.

I used the following code on the Joomla article:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<iframe src="http://localhost/" name="myiframe" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

However, the built-in Joomla editor doesn't allow iframes to be used on an article. It just deletes them. To get around this, I used phpMyAdmin to browse through the Joomla database.

I searched the prefix_content table for the article I wanted, and manually edited the row for that article, typing the html code in there.

The resulting iframe can now retain all the functionalities of CodeIgniter, and is nicely isolated into the iframe.

Like I said, not an elegant solution since I needed to alter the database directly, but there might be a Joomla extension around that allows iframes to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of plugins in the JED.
Here's an exemple : 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/16450?qh=YTo0OntpOjA7czo2OiJpZnJhbWUiO2k6MTtzOjc6ImlmcmFtZXMiO2k6MjtzOjc6ImlmcmFtZWQiO2k6MztzOjg6ImlmcmFtZSdzIjt9